# Delete rows with ajax and php

Tags: php, ajax, checkbox

Is this a good way, to delete all the selected rows from sql table?

The code works fine, but maybe there other or better ways to do this. The real_ escape_string function is in the good place, or i should put in in the foreach loop, before the sql query?

```
$('.deleteRows').click(function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    var val = [];
    if(confirm("Biztos, hogy törölni szeretné a kijelölt sorokat?"))
    {
        $(':checkbox:checked').each(function(i){
          val[i] = $(this).val();
        });
        $.ajax({
            data: { val:val },
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'files/delete_all_uzenet.php',
            success: function(data) 
            {
                var result = $.trim(data);
                $('#newsletterResult').html(data);
                $('#newsletterModal').modal('show');
            },
            complete: function()
            {
                setTimeout(function() 
                {
                    location.reload();  
                }, 4000 );  
            }
        });
    }
    return false;
});
```

Php file:

```
<?php
include_once("../../files/connect.php");
if(isset($_POST['val']))
{
    foreach($_POST['val'] as $v)
    {
        mysqli_query($kapcs, $sql = "DELETE FROM kapcsolatfelvetel WHERE kapcsolat_id = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($kapcs, $v)."'") or die(mysqli_error($kapcs));
    }
    echo 'Rows deleted';
}
else
{
    exit("No rows selected.");
}
?>
```

Comment: No not really, use prepared parameterised queries to avois SQL Injection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code will execute a lot faster if you merge all operations in a single query. Once you've verified that you have values to delete, do something such as:

```
$p = &$_POST['val']; //$p refers to $_POST['val'];

//clean all inputs
foreach($p as &$v) $v = "'". mysqli_escape_string($kapcs,$v) ."'";

//transform to "('value1', 'value2'...)"
$values = '('.implode(',',$p).')';

//build one sql to delete all rows
$sql = "DELETE FROM kapcsolatfelvetel WHERE kapcsolat_id IN $values";
```

You can then run the query to delete all rows at once.

PS: You use string escaping to clean your strings; that's much better than nothing, but not as good as prepared statements and parameterized queries.

PPS: You should also check that your query executed successfully. It's a mistake to assume that just because you called `mysqli_query`, the rows were deleted.

Comment: Thanks, i will check it tomorrow.

$p = &$_POST['val'] - What does the &-character mean?

And...$values = '('.implode(','$p).')';

In the implode, why you writed $p? Not $v?

Comment: @TakácsZoltán `&` sets `$_POST` and `$p` to the same reference in memory. Without it, `$p` would just be a copy, meaning if you add a value to one, it is not added to the other. With it, they refer to the same thing by different names, so changing one also changes the other.   As for your 2nd question, look at the documentation for `implode`.  It takes the array that has the values you want to glue together. So I used `$p` since that's the array.

Comment: I get sytax error for this:  $values = '('.implode(','$p).')';

Comment: @TakácsZoltán I was missing a comma just before `$p`. I've added it.

Comment: And before deleting, how can i check, that the rows(ID-s) are realy in the table?

Comment: @TakácsZoltán You got it; When there is an error, `mysqli_query()` returns `false`, so doing `mysqli_query(...) or die(mysqli_error(...))` will abort and show any error. If the code gets to the next line, then you know the query executed successfully.  If you use my code as the basis for the solution to your initial question, remember to upvote and select my answer.  Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

@BeetleJuice

So, this is the right way?

```
    <?php
include_once("../../files/connect.php");
if(isset($_POST['val']))
{
    $p = &$_POST['val'];
    foreach($p as &$v)
    {
        $v = "'". mysqli_escape_string($kapcs, $v) ."'";
    }
    $values = '('.implode(',',$p).')';

    mysqli_query($kapcs, $sql = "DELETE FROM kapcsolatfelvetel WHERE kapcsolat_id IN $values") or die(mysqli_error($kapcs));
    echo 'Rows deleted ok.';
}
else
{
    exit("No rows selected.");
}
?>
```